# Why Illustrator changes anchor points position in exported SVG's?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

When I open back the exported via **Asset Export** SVG's some anchor points in certain circumstances change their position while maintaining the original shape of the curve. I made some screens: points on the first keep their position, while on the other two points are shifted.

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it a bug or some kind of optimization?

Illustrator CC 2018 on Win 10 x64.

[image: Point are the same]
[image: Points shifted]
[image: Points are shifted]

Comment: I think possibly only Adobe could answer this.

Comment: howmany decimal points are you using?

Comment: @joojaa 2, tried 3 to no avail.

Comment: Try 14 instead of a really low value of 3

Comment: @joojaa the maximum is 5, and 2 is pretty high for most cases, and 3 is actually really high and for tiny vectors.

Comment: Not really internally illustrator stores values as double floats which means about 15 digits of precicion to rule out some massive rounding error we need to up the value as high as it can go. For example there might be a massive offset from origin that is causing this.

Comment: @joojaa Not really what? Are we talking about "Decimal" field in SVG Format Settings in Asset Export Options? The maximum possible value is 5. 2 is clearly enough for precision for the objects on my references. The other points are exactly on the same places, no rounding errors. How can I increase this value to 14? And how can one hundred trillionth of a pixel accuracy (if I get it right) correct this error?
You mean the document zero? I created a document the size of an object (the last reference) and set the decimal to 5. The error is in place.

Comment: Part of deducing what the problem is is to use best effort to rule things out.   If precicion is on the table you expand to max to rule it out.   Computers dont use fixed point math so even if your precision is 3 decimals correct the system below does not accurately represent the situation as the floats precision degrades over distabce from origin, all kinds of counterintuitive rounding problems are common sources of errors.

Comment: Also, trying to remotely debug something like this is almost impossible unless you are willing work with us. Unfortunately for any person doing so you are most likely source of error so they have to be skeptical for any of your claims.

Comment: @joojaa the information I provide is easy to reproduce for the people who use such programs on everyday basis as professionals and I address my question to these people. Moreover a necessary condition for the usefulness of the answer is a thorough knowledge of the program and the ability to reproduce an error locally.
Thanks for your thoughts anyway, we all source of errors in some way...

Comment: Problem is that i can not reproduce this error on my illustrator.

Comment: Although, it does resemble a error that illustrator used to have in the past regarding rounding of edges. In anycase you have now ruled the question offtopic for this site.

Comment: @joojaa What is your version? Can you please share the results of your test ai and svg files? And what is the reason for your opinion that my question may not be relevant for this community?

Comment: Because graphic design is not really about technical underpinning. But rather how to carry the visual language through. So while im interested in researching how adobe implementation details thats not really what most people into graphic design want. Which is why one of the answers is only adobe knows. This question requires your specific setup and is technical support, which is out of scope.

Comment: @joojaa Well, but I see the opposite here: many, if not most, questions concern technical details about using tools, not "visual language". Also from my experience very often relevant communities are more useful than support teams. That's why I'm here. And no specific setup is required for my question, just Adobe Illustrator CC 2018. Moreover these days the "visual language" alone, without knowing the necessary technical features is no more than useless pixels on the screen.

Comment: Well, still this is a support issue because i tested this in cc 2018 at work and i still can not replicate the issue.

Comment: I *can* reproduce the issue in CC 2019. I've redrawn your last example and exported using *Assets Export* with different combinations of settings. All with the same result as you get. If I simply *Save As* svg, the points don't change. Can't tell you *why* though and I'm thinking about closing the question for the same reasons as @joojaa. (Btw: Your comment about not needing many decimals for small vectors doesn't make sense. The smaller the graphics, the more decimals are (potentially) needed.)

Comment: @Wolff My comment? I didn't say such things. I said _2 is pretty high for most cases, and 3 is actually really high and for tiny vectors._ And 4 or 5 is presumably for very small vectors, something like 3x3 or 2x2 pixels.
I also asked on Adobe Support Community and didn't get answer either.

Comment: OK, I thought you meant that 22x16 px was a tiny vector. Anyway it all depends on the graphics.